# setting up django server for receiving callbacks from jira and other apis

Tags: django, callback, django-rest-framework, python-jira

how can I start receiving and parsing callback api's responds in further with Django server?

I wanna setup my DRF server to start working with JIRA webhooks, but also it might be useful for other apis such as telegram and etc. In this case I need to provide them my server's url where I would expect new events/data, but atm I don't realise what it means exactly. Where do I need to start digging in?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about the apis you are talking about but if the api sends some callbacks you'll give them a url, mysite.com/whatever

make your url config like normal 
and in your view you can parse the result

```
def my_callback_view(request):
  # assuming it's a POST request 
  data = request.POST
  ... do whatever with the data
```

Comment: but to receive callbacks I need to deploy it on some server so my url would become reachable?

Comment: yeah. for development could use dummy data in the format you expect until your site is online. Or have it on a heroku app or something if you need